# Eloquent - using Union to combine two symmetric relationships throws error

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I built a many-to-many relationship between users as friends through a pivot table. They have to have different foreign keys in the pivot (`friends`) table, `user_from_id`, `user_to_id`.

In the User model, I define two relationship:

```
public function friends_from() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User,'friends',
   'user_from_id`, `user_to_id`);
}
```

... and `friends_to` symmetrically, which works fine.

But it still makes it hard to consolidate just all "my friends. I thought I found a really clever approach by combining them in a "friends" method and still have a builder, tried to do a union of the two relationship methods:

```
public function friends() {
  return $this->friends_to()->unionAll($this->friends_from());
}
```

But this generates an SQL exception:

```
Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

The SQL:

```
select
`users`.*, `friends`.`user_from_id` as `pivot_user_from_id`,
`friends.user_to_id` as `pivot_user_to_id`
from `users`
inner join `friends`
on `users`.`id` = `friends`.`user_to_id`
where `friends`.`user_from_id` = 245)

union all 
(select * from `users` inner join `friends`
on `users`.`id` =           `friends`.`user_from_id`
where `friends`.`user_to_id` = 245)
```

So it looks close but I'm missing something essential.  Any insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also came with this problem and i found this solution

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23862#issuecomment-505652825

you need to add getQuery() method

```
$this->friends_to()->getQuery()->unionAll($this->friends_from())
```