# Laravel 5.3 Many to many relationship with same model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am working on a CRM where I have a User model which can have many to many relationships with other User's and a type of relationship which is defined through the pivot table.

For example:

Tim -> Tom ( co-worker )

Tim -> Steve ( family member )

Tim -> Jon ( neighbors )

In my User model I have this where I'm using user1_id and user2_id from the pivot table as foreign keys:

```
public function relationships ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,null,'user1_id','user2_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('type');
}
```

Which works fine in one direction. So if I call this:

```
User::find($timsID)->relationships;
```

That works as expected and I'll get Tom Steve and Jon as results. Now, if I were to use Tom's ID in that query instead, Tim won't return as a relationship since it's searching on user1_id when Tom's ID is stored in user2.

Is there a solution to pull the records if there's a match from either foreign key? I don't want to have to store 2 records for each relationship.

Comment: What is your pivot table? you seem to pass `null`.

Comment: It's user_user. I pass null since I followed the laravel naming convention and it defaults to that when passed null.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted, seems a fair question to me?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume I sort of understood what you want to do. Relationships in Laravel work in both directions. In your case, you have only defined ONE direction, but want to use it in both directions. To clear what I mean

```
public function peopleIKnow() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,null,'user1_id','user2_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('type');
}

public function peopleWhoKnowMe() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,null,'user2_id','user1_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('type');
}
```

This way you have two way relationship. You can build on top of this idea to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks I understand that but in this case now I'll have to make 2 calls that do 2 queries for one set of results. Even if I were to do that, how would I merge the 2 sets of results into one collection?

Comment: Thanks you for downvoting me even though I'm the only one trying to help you. Anyway, for what you are trying to do, you will have to give up on Eloquent and get it with a query of your own where you check either `user1_id` or `user2_id`.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and if I did it wasn't intentional at all. Just upvoted you actually.

Comment: I was thinking you could create a helper function and union the two - but this poster appears to have tried something like that without success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637478/eloquent-using-union-to-combine-two-symmetric-relationships-throws-error